# RFC 2544 / Y1564 software implementation

Tags: networking, performance, benchmark

Is there any [RFC 2544](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2544.txt) and/or [Y1564](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU-T%5fY.1564) software available for Linux?

I'm aware that tools like `iperf`, `bw-ng` and `bmon` exist, but I was not able to find something that mimics Ethernet tester functionality with RFC2544 and Y1564 tests...

Alternatively, can anyone recommend some advanced traffic generator (with multiple Ethernet frame size support) and advanced network statistics monitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ostinato](https://code.google.com/p/ostinato/) looks to be one such tool that you're looking for.

> Ostinato is an open-source, cross-platform network packet crafter/traffic generator and analyzer with a friendly GUI. Craft and send packets of several streams with different protocols at different rates.

#### Screenshot

[image: ss of app]

#### Screencast

- [Ostinato Packet/Traffic Generator](http://youtu.be/On64lQYEFlY)

#### Features

- Runs on Windows, Linux, BSD and Mac OS X (Will probably run on other platforms also with little or no modification but this hasn't been tested)
- Open, edit, replay and save PCAP files
- Support for the most common standard protocols

  - Ethernet/802.3/LLC SNAP
  - VLAN (with QinQ)
  - ARP, IPv4, IPv6, IP-in-IP a.k.a IP Tunnelling (6over4, 4over6, 4over4, 6over6)
  - TCP, UDP, ICMPv4, ICMPv6, IGMP, MLD
  - Any text based protocol (HTTP, SIP, RTSP, NNTP etc.)
  - More protocols in the works ...
- Modify any field of any protocol (some protocols allow changing packet fields with every packet at run time e.g. changing IP/MAC addresses)
- User provided Hex Dump - specify some or all bytes in a packet
- User defined script to substitute for an unimplemented protocol (EXPERIMENTAL)
- Stack protocols in any arbitrary order
- Create and configure multiple streams
- Configure stream rates, bursts, no. of packets
- Single client can control and configure multiple ports on multiple computers generating traffic
- Exclusive control of a port to prevent the OS from sending stray packets provides a controlled testing environment
- Statistics Window shows realtime port receive/transmit statistics and rates
- Capture packets and view them (needs Wireshark to view the captured packets)
- Framework to add new protocol builders easily

#### Downloading

Many [pre-built packages](http://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home:pstavirs:ostinato&package=ostinato) for various distros are made available through SuSE's Open Build Service (OBS).